# Como setar informações no cookie dentro de uma controller Symfony2

Tags: symfony-2

Preciso setar algumas informações no cookie quando um novo usuário cria seu cadastro no sistema.
A tela de cadastro é essa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Tenho a seguinte controller:**

```html
<?php
/**
 * Exibe o convite para usuários anônimos.
 * @Route("/aceitar", name="convite_aceitar")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 * @Template("ClienteBundle:/Convite:cadastrar.html.twig")
 * @ParamConverter("convite", options={"mapping": {"token": "token"}})
 */
public

function exibirConviteParaAnonimoAction(Request $request, UserConvite $convite)
{
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
$formCadastro->handleRequest($request);
if ($formCadastro->isValid()) {
 try {
  $user = $formCadastro->getData();
  $userConvidado = $manager->aceitarConvite($convite, $user);
  $manager->autenticaUsuario($userConvidado);

 $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Convite aceito com sucesso.');
 return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('contrato_list', array()));
}
   catch(Exception $e) {
    $msg = "Oops! Ocorreu um erro. <br />" . $e->getMessage();
    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->set('error', $msg);
   }
  }
 }

 $params['form_cadastro'] = $formCadastro->createView();
 return $params;
}
```

**O metodo autenticaUsuario é o seguinte:**

```html
 

<?php
public

function autenticaUsuario(Usuario $usuario)
{
 $providerKey = 'usuario_conta'; // your firewall name
 $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($usuario, null, $providerKey, $usuario->getRoles());
 $this->securityContext->setToken($token);
 return $token;
}

OcookiequequerosetaréumJWTeometodoestálocalizadoemAuxiliarManager::setJWTCookie()
/**
 *
 * Cria o JWT para o usuario em questão e salva no Cookie do navegador.
 * @param Request $request
 * @param UserInterface $user
 * @param Response $response
 */
public

function setJWTCookie(Request $request, Usuario $user, Response $response)
{
 $baseUrl = $this->getDominioBase($request->getHost());
 $jwt = $this->jwtManager->create($user);
 $cookieJWT = new Cookie('user_jwt', $jwt, 0, '/', '.' . $baseUrl, true, false);
 $response->headers->setCookie($cookieJWT);
 $this->getUsuarioManager()->autenticaUsuario($user);
 return $cookieJWT;
}
```

Obs: O metodo $this->getUsuarioManager()->autenticaUsuario($user) é igual ao citado acima.

Alguem poderia me dar uma luz de como setar essas informações e retornar a $response na controller?